# How to get topic name and client id from aws mqtt message broker to aws lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-iot, aws-serverless

After mapping send message to lambda function, in AWS IoT core with query `SELECT * From '+'`, I am getting only messages in aws lambda event object. I am using python 3. How can I get topic name and client Id along with messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The topic and client id need to be passed in the IoT rule using the [`topic()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.html#iot-function-topic) and [`clientid()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.html#iot-sql-function-clientid) functions. These are then available in the payload that the lambda receives.

So the rule can be:

```
SELECT *, topic() AS topic, clientid() AS clientid FROM '+'
```

The lambda will then receive a JSON payload with the `topic` and `clientid` properties.